# How to write CSS selector for a parent element

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

I have tried `:parent`, but it did not work:

Eg:

```
card-paragraph-textbox.blue-highlight :parent .edit-Text
```

**Class Name of child:** `card-paragraph-textbox.blue-highlight`.

**Class Name of parent:** `.edit-Text`.

**Keyword:** `:parent`

Please help on this!!

Comment: I don't know Selenium, but it's not possible using CSS alone. See [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/1016716)

Comment: There are atleast 5 ways of accessing elements in Selenium. What all attempts have you failed at? Share the code..

Comment: I just tried the above mentioned syntax childClass : parent

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: @XXX, was my answer helpful? If yes -- check a tick near my answer, please.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way, use XPath instead.

Get parent:

```
//*[@class='edit-Text']
```

Get parent via child:

```
//*[@class='card-paragraph-textbox blue-highlight']/..
```

or

```
//*[@class='card-paragraph-textbox blue-highlight']/parent::*
```